Does a party have to wait 1d4 hours to start a Short Rest if no healing is available and an ally is only stabilized?
The rules for Short Rests say:

To start a Short Rest, you must have at least 1 Hit Point.

The rules for Long Rests say:

To start a Long Rest, you must have at least 1 Hit Point.

The rules for Stabilizing a Character say:

A Stable creature doesn’t make Death Saving Throws even though it has 0 Hit Points, but it still has the Unconscious condition. If the creature takes damage, it stops being Stable and starts making Death Saving Throws again. A Stable creature that isn’t healed regains 1 Hit Point after 1d4 hours.

and the rules for Death Saving Throws say:

When you roll a 1 on the d20 for a Death Saving Throw, you suffer two failures. If you roll a 20 on the d20, you regain 1 Hit Point.

The way I read this, it seems like if a party is completely out of healing and trying to keep an ally from dying, they will have to wait a full 1d4 hours before they can even begin any kind of rest to recover (whether using hit dice or slot recovery). In such a situation, it seems the most effective way out is for someone to stab the stable ally thereby causing them to resume making Death Saving Throws again (but not start with a failure) and wait for them to roll a 20 and if they don't, cast Spare the Dying and repeat the process.
Is that accurate? Because it seems a bit absurd.

Maybe I’m missing something, but can’t the rest of the party rest while the ally is unconscious?

@ThomasMarkov they can, but it'd be bad form at the table to have everyone else ready to go and someone still having to sit out because their character isn't stable.

@Pyrotechnical: If your party has literally no slots left for casting a single healing spell (and therefore said healers likely have no other casting ability at all), nor any other healing resource, I'd argue that everybody else is not ready to go.

@ShadowRanger suppose the group's only level 2 and comprised solely of martial characters? If any of them go down, there may not be a way for them to get back up. Fighters have Second Wind, but they can't use it if a crit drops them to 0 instantly.

[5e-2014], but perhaps related from a design perspective: Can a zero-HP, unconscious and stable character be woken up prematurely?, How does Sildar Hallwinter regain HP in Lost Mine of Phandelver adventure?

Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, and general advice related to the asker's problem do not belong in comments.

This is only a change to short rests
Long rests required a creature to have 1 hit point in the 2014 rules as well. From the end of the 2014 description of long rests:

A character can't benefit from more than one long rest in a 24-hour period, and a character must have at least 1 hit point at the start of the rest to gain its benefits.

Only the unconscious party member would have to wait
You’re correct that, should no healing be available, a party member who is unconscious but stable and has zero hit points will have to wait to recover before they can benefit from a rest.
However there’s nothing to stop the rest of the party from resting while their fallen comrade recovers. This might allow them to regain use of a healing ability and patch up their fallen friend, who they can watch over for an hour while they rest, or who they can protect (if they’re vulnerable because of a lack of short rest recharge abilities etc) until they can all take a long rest.
This change makes suffering a near-fatal wound more dangerous, which seems to be the intent (though I couldn’t find a designer source to confirm this).
Another consideration is that many sources of healing are improved in the 2024 rules: the revised cure wounds and healing word for example now restore twice as many dice of hit points, and mandatory origin feats make it likely someone is a healer with access to non-magical healing. So it’s much less likely a party will run out of healing before they get a moment to rest.

You're reading it correctly
If the party is completely out of healing magic, potions, and anything else that can restore HP, then aside from your metagaming exploit (I'd give a rather stern look to any party members repeatedly cutting on their buddy and restabilizing for a benefit that's definitely not something any in-game character should be aware of), the options are:

The rest of the party short rests to recover healing magic (e.g. a Cleric that has run out of Channel Divinity could short rest to recover it, then use it with the optional Harness Divine Power ability to recover a slot to cast a healing spell), then heals the stabilized individual, who can then rest immediately
Wait 1d4 hours to recover 1 HP and rest as normal

Frankly, 5E 2024 is already one of the most forgiving editions on natural healing (a single long rest provides complete HP recovery & complete Hit Dice recovery; original 5E, already quite generous, only gave back half the expended Hit Dice). That someone can completely recover their health and healing capacity, from being wounded to the brink of death, with no magic at all, in the space of 1d4+8 hours, feels plenty generous, healing-wise. If you don't want to wait 1d4 hours, save slots for healing, take the Healer feat and keep healer's kits on hand, or just stock up on healing potions.

I will concede that being completely out of healing options is a rarity in most situations (i.e. levels 3+), but it's not that uncommon an occurrence at very low levels (i.e. levels 1-2). The nature of my question stems from keeping things fun for all the players and this was a distinct change between editions. Additionally, the inclusion of this requirement sort of creates a mandate for a healer to be in the party because the Wisdom (Medicine) skill check still doesn't allow for recovery of any hit points innately.

@Pyrotechnical: I'd argue that in most games, despite the official guidance, multiple back-to-back encounters that are hard enough to put a character down, and would allow an hour for short rests between them, but not 1d4+1 hours if really needed, are just not that common; how often can you mostly guarantee safety for an hour, but not 1d4+1 hours? Back when short rests were five minutes long (in 4E), okay, the difference between five minutes and multiple hours was huge, but we're not talking an order of magnitude difference with one hour short rests.

And while the latest editions are definitely trying to avoid the 2E issue of a party being crippled unless you force someone to play a dedicated party healer, they do make it so healers aren't just healers (filling your 2E Cleric's spellcasting over half full of healing spells, just in case, was always a drag). Requiring that someone play any of a Bard, Cleric, Druid, Paladin, Ranger, Alchemist, or a subclass of one of the other caster classes that adds healing (e.g. Celestial Warlock, Divine Soul Sorcerer) and hold onto a tiny bit of their resources for this purpose isn't that bad.

@ShadowRanger also factor in that everyone gets a feat and humans get two, so someone is likely to be a Healer, plus there are crafting rules for potions of healing, so there are more and stronger sources of healing than before. Making them feel a bit necessary seems fair.
